# Empty elements - which is better

Tags: xml

When creating an XML document with several elements from information that is sent from another device, and let’s say some of the information was not sent (ex the SecFile ID information), is it better to receive this XML with (a)the element not there, or (b)empty element, or (c)with a  element inserted or (d)an attribute xsi:nil=”true” inserted?

Ex
All the information

```
<FilmFile_ID>
<Film_ID>02</Film_ID>
<PriFile_ID>08</PriFile_ID>
<SecFile_ID>03</SecFile_ID>
</FilmFile_ID>
```

a)SecFile_ID element removed

```
<FilmFile_ID>
<Film_ID>02</Film_ID>
<PriFile_ID>08</PriFile_ID>
</FilmFile_ID>
```

b)SecFile_ID empty

```
<FilmFile_ID>
<Film_ID>02</Film_ID>
<PriFile_ID>08</PriFile_ID>
<SecFile_ID></SecFile_ID>
</FilmFile_ID>
```

c) inserted

```
<FilmFile_ID>
<Film_ID>02</Film_ID>
<PriFile_ID>08</PriFile_ID>
<SecFile_ID><null/></SecFile_ID>
</FilmFile_ID>
```

d)xsi:nil=”true” inserted

```
<FilmFile_ID>
<Film_ID>02</Film_ID>
<PriFile_ID>08</PriFile_ID>
<SecFile_ID xsi:nil=”true”/>
</FilmFile_ID>'
```

Comment: All are valid, there's no "better" way. It's up to your application.

Comment: I guess the slight advantage of "element not there" is that your XML message will be a bit smaller... a little bit...

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no "better" way, but, you could still argue that:

- b) is ambiguous, since you cannot really know if it means an *empty*  or a *non-existent* value, and that
- c) introduces an unnecessary complication in dealing with a special data type, and that
- d) conveys exacly the same meaning as a), but with a lot more verbosity, hence
- a) wins

If you go with a), then `<SecFile></SecFile>`, should be interpreted as an "empty" value (not null), if that is permissible by the Application (or schema).

Answer (score 0):

Generally the XML culture is that you as the document designer get to choose what syntax to use for particular semantics, or in other words, the document means what you say it means. If you need to distinguish different kinds of absent value (e.g. "John has no middle name" from "I don't know John's middle name") then the distinction can be important, but in most cases you can use any of these quite happily. Using an empty element may make life a little bit easier for applications consuming the XML.